# images inside div's not resize equal when screen resizes

Tags: html, image, css

Ok, let me try to explain the issue.
I have 3 div's, each set with a same width and same max-height.
When I resize the screen, the images inside those div's are equally sized (keeping their dimension ratio).
The issue is that not all the images are the same size, which leads to the point that not all div's resize correctly. They tend to get their height from the image, the images are not all equal in height, in width they are.

[This is how the issue looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFUHk.png)

[It should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezsLh.png)

Hope this makes sense.

Cheers,

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: http://www.codeply.com/go/tUYdTRYYAc

Comment: @Banzay thanks, that is the closest of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Because you said that each div has an height defined, you can give all the images 
 `height: 100%;` to prevent the images from stretching you can also give them
         `"object-fit:cover"`.
notice that object-fit has poor support on IE.
that way all of your images will fill the entire div without hurting their ratio.

If you need to support internet explorer, maybe you should consider background-image, backgorund-size:cover for this case;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="images">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
    </div>
    <div class="images">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
    </div>
    <div class="images">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x250">
    </div>
</div>

.container {
    display: flex;
}

.images img {
    min-height: 200px;
    max-width: 200px;
    min-width: 100%;
}
```

live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/h02a31df/